# Getting parameters from url in react-router without the # sign

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use a third party authentication resource that my client wants(WeChat).  This works by authenticating on their site and then redirecting the user to the URL that we give with a "code" parameter.  It does not support adding a /#/ at the end of the url.  So I am getting back

```
www.mywebsitedomain.com/code=test123
```

I am using react-router and so it automatically changes it to

```
www.mywebsitedomain.com/code=test123#/?_k=1dcv0i
```

so that code does not show up in props.location or props.params.

I cannot figure out how to get that code.

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a history component to handle that in react-router.

```
import { useBasename } from 'history'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

export default useBasename(createBrowserHistory)({ basename: '/yourUrlBase' });
```

Then import this file in your main/app/index.js

To change the route you need to use a pushState.

```
history.pushState(null, '/internalUrl/' + urlParameters);
```

And your route should be:

```
<Route path="internalUrl/:urlParameters" component={YourView} />
```

Also you can find a bit more info and a complete tutorial on this link: https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/#article-header-id-9

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am a bit confused though.  I see that you export useBasename and then you say to import it....but I do not see where you use it.  What are you supposed to do with useBasename once imported?

Comment: Hi James, this is the path to the folder of the project, like /build or something, this ishow the router should handle the folder path, ignoring it and loading data from this point.